# Run JavaScript from a TextArea

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, algorithm

I have to create an application in Node.js that executes algorithms (in js) and create graphs with their results. 
My problem is that I don't really know how to execute the JavaScript in my textarea, I didn't find a plugin that can run a javascript code in node.js.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the textarea?  Are you simply trying to read whatever value it has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also found that https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html which is perfect !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.eval("some string of javascript") in most any JS dialect and it will run the code inside.  See more info here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

It's pretty obvious this is for school, but as a general practice using JSON.eval() is not recommended as it's a nice attack vector for running any code someone wants.  However, it will work in node JS or on the client side in your browser wherever you insert it.  As long as it's for a learning exercise it might be what you need, but don't go getting a job and using .eval() all over the place.

here's a copy paste of the warning from that page I linked to on developer.mozilla.org

> Don't use eval needlessly!
>   eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is not susceptible.

Comment: Thank you !
I also talked to a PhD today and he told me to use eval too.
I explained him the issue in details and he explained me I should create a child process in order to have control on the execution (pause, stop ,etc)

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing a few concepts here.
Node.js is server side javascript whereas your textarea in the browser is client side javascript.

To solve your current problem, you could either put the algorithm in the client or you could write some sort of REST service on the server side and call that service from the client.

Hope that helps